# How to find expiration date of an imported pgp key

Tags: linux, pgp, webmethods

i have already imported Partner's pgp key in my server & its working fine.. Now i want to find the expiration details of the imported pgp key.

Could someone share the command to do that ??

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is just to list the key with the command `gpg --list-key [KEY ID]`. It should output something like:

```
pub   rsa4096 2016-05-25 [SC] [expires: 2025-01-13]
      VERYLONGKEYID
uid           [ultimate] Name Surname <email@address.com>
sub   rsa4096 2016-05-25 [E] [expires: 2025-01-13]
```

Naturally, what you are looking for is in the brackets where you can read "expires: date".